# JSLint: Disallow state.<something> in Redux connect functon

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, eslint

Need to write a (custom) ESLint rule for this:

**Good**:

```js
connect((state, props) => {
  return {
     organizations: Organization.getActive(state, props.user),
    ...
    <prop>: Model.scope(state, prop...),  

  };
})(MyComponent);
```

**Bad**: All the stuff in there

```js
connect((state, props) => {
  return {
     organizations: state.organizations, //archived? suspended? or really all?
  };
})(MyComponent);
```

**Bad**: Filtering in place.

```js
connect((state, props) => {
  return {
     organizations: filter(state.organizations, {
       status: Organization.ACTIVE
     }),
  };
})(MyComponent);
```

All that should be needed is to disallow `state.<something>` within the connect function as a starting point and make tweaks as needed.

Comment: what did you try and didn't work? can you show us some code and we can help you afterwards.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, hoping this is general / similar enough that someone already knows the right approach.

Comment: How did you mean "Write a JSLint rule for this"? JSLint the tool is [maintained by Douglas Crockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint). He writes all the rules. ;) Did you mean a [custom _eslint_  rule](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules)?

Comment: Yep I meant a custom one.

Comment: I read your question several times, but I don't understand what you want. can you explain more?

Comment: I want to avoid accessing the state directly via `state.organizations`, I, want people to use class methods instead: `Organization.getActive(state)`.

Comment: I've never seen that before. I guess you wanna bring another programming language culture here. When whole the React community are going to FP and easy accessing data, by my thoughts, there is no need Class, OOP, .Net like data accessing. ok. good luck

Comment: @hakunin Have you considered writing ESLint plugin for your custom rule the way it is outlined in [Writing custom ESLint rules](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2016/05/27/writing-custom-eslint-rules/)?